# Create Fourier-Series of f(x) = x if 0 < x < Pi and 0 if Pi < x < 2*Pi

Tags: fourier-series

I tried the following to create the Fourier-series of the function:

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}  x & 0<x<\pi \\ 0 & \pi < x < 2 \pi   \end{cases}$$

This is what I tried:

$$a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi x dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\left(\frac{x^2}{2}|_0^\pi\right) = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{2} = \frac{\pi^2}{2\cdot\pi} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Is that right?

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi x \cdot \cos(nx) dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\left(\frac{x \cdot \sin(nx)}{n} + \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}\right)|_0^\pi$$

Assuming that $\sin(nx)$ is always $0$ and $\cos(nx)$ is $(-1)^n$. Is that ok??

$$   = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\left(\frac{0}{n} + \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right) = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right) = \frac{(-1)^n}{\pi n^2}$$

That's already wrong I'm sure!

$$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi x \sin(nx) dx = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\left(\frac{x \cdot \cos(nx)}{n} + \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\right)|_0^\pi$$

Assuming that $\sin(nx)$ is always $0$ and $\cos(nx)$ is $(-1)^n$. Is that ok??

$$   = \frac{1}{\pi}\cdot\left(\frac{\pi \cdot (-1)^n}{n}\right)   = \frac{\pi\cdot(-1)^n}{\pi n} = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ voila, thats wrong again :-)

A solution would be great, but I also need to understand what was my mistake.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is an old post, but for anyone coming to this now: one issue I see is the integral for a0 at the beginning. It should be done from -pi to pi, not zero to pi.

Comment: @Jake This is obviously not an issue at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging in $x=0$ and $x=\pi$ in $\sin (nx)$ indeed gives you $0$.

Plugging in $x=\pi$ in $\cos (nx)$ indeed gives you $(-1)^n$.

But don't forget that plugging in $x=0$ in $\cos (nx)$ gives you $1$.

Also, in the integral for $b_n$, there seems to be a minus sign missing after the integration by parts. Recheck your calculation.

Comment: But don't forget that plugging in x=0 in cos(nx) gives you 1. --> Yes, that was an Issue in the an calculation. Should I correct this finding in the initial question or what would be the proper way on Stackexchange?

Comment: But I don't get where the minus in bn might be missing?

Comment: What is the *anti*-derivative of $\sin x$?

Comment: Since you asked about a mistake in your calculation, it is better to leave the mistake as-is in the question, so future readers will know what the question and answer were about.

Comment: Uuups, right, the anti-derivative is: -(x * cos(nx) / n)) + (sin(nx) / n²)